# Alert based on GCP logs with MQL

Tags: gcloud

So, from my understanding MQL is used for advanced metrics and not something simple like Log based alert but is it possible to Alert from GCP log. The log comes as output of cronjob running in Kubernetes.

Comment: The question is if it’s possible to add log based metrics in general or log based metric with MQL only ?

Comment: Adding log based metrics with MQL